# What did Tim Curry say in the movie Congo to Ernie Hudson after being insulted?

Tags: dialogue, congo

I've watched this on TV, and the line in question follows Hudson's remarks about Tim Curry's character doing a lot of good, but only for himself.
Tim Curry's character says(what I think he says) "Shut up you fucking..."
This line was on TV. like normal programming. Does he actually say that or is it something else-if so what?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### He uses the word "filthy"

> Oh, he's Romanian. And he has done good, but mostly for Mr. Homolka.
>
> **Shut up, you filthy...**
>
> Filthy what?

Read more: https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=congo

Comment: Well done, I was about to include a script from another location but it's good to see that the dialogue matches

Comment: That is 1 hell of an accent......

Comment: I am sad to admit that *Congo* was probably my first exposure to Tim Curry, it's only after seeing him in *Muppet Treasure Island* did I come to appreciate his versatility and long career